# Float datatype in tensorflow C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am unable to find the float datatype in tensorflow namespace. Can anyone explicitly let me know what is the datatype for handling floating point numbers in **C++** API? Please indicate whatever appropriate file I may have to include as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DT_FLOAT is defined in a generated header file. After you build TensorFlow from the source code, you will get bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h. DT_FLOAT is defined there.

In your code, you will use
tensorflow/core/platform/types.h to include that generated header.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you include their tensorflow/core/framework/types.h file, it will work? [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/types.h#L187) is a spot where they mention DT_FLOAT on GitHub.

Comment: I did so, didn't work. It returned me a warning that the declaration has no meaning which finally culminated in an error because the variable was not found in the scope.